# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'roll_belt' not found in predict

Tags: r, predict

In the call, at the end of the code, to:

```
predict(pml_training_rf_model_1, pml_validation$classe)
```

I get the error:

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'roll_belt' not found

That was because I should be calling the function like this:

```
predict(pml_training_rf_model_1, pml_validation)
```

The "roll_belt" attribute does appear in the data frames I am using, so I was clearly making some other mistake, which is now corrected and saved for posterity.

```
#Start code

rm(list=ls())
library("caret")
library("data.table")
library("randomForest")

set.seed(12345)
pml_training_file <- "pml-training.csv"
pml_testing_file <- "pml-testing.csv"

if (!file.exists(pml_training_file)) {
  pml_training_url <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv"
  download.file(pml_training_url, pml_training_file)
}

pml_testing_file <- "pml-testing.csv"
if (!file.exists(pml_testing_file)) {
  pml_testing_url <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-testing.csv"
  download.file(pml_testing_url, pml_testing_file)
}

pml_training_original <- fread(pml_training_file, na.strings=c("NA","#DIV/0!",""), data.table = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

partition_index <- createDataPartition(y=pml_training_original$classe, p=0.6, list = FALSE)
pml_training <- pml_training_original[partition_index,]
pml_validation <-  pml_training_original[-partition_index,]

#Remove metadata columns
pml_training <- pml_training[,-c(1:7)]

#Remove columns where the number of NA results is above a given level
na_level = .75
nrow_pml_training = nrow(pml_training)
na_col_nums <- numeric()
for(i in 1:length(pml_training)) {
  sum_na = sum(is.na(pml_training[, i]))
  if(sum_na/nrow_pml_training >= na_level ) {
    na_col_nums <- c(na_col_nums, i)           
  }
}
pml_training <- pml_training[-na_col_nums]

#Set the columns in the validation data to be the same as those in the training data
pml_training_colnames <- colnames(pml_training)
pml_validation <- pml_validation[, pml_training_colnames]

pml_training_rf_model_1 <- randomForest(classe ~ ., data=pml_training)
#Wrong! pml_training_predictions_1 <- predict(pml_training_rf_model_1, pml_validation$classe)
pml_training_predictions_1 <- predict(pml_training_rf_model_1, pml_validation)
confusionMatrix(pml_validation$classe, pml_training_predictions_1)
```

Comment: Proof that roll_belt is in pml_validation$classe. Because I believe R when it says it's not there.

Comment: You would need to provide an example of input data that makes it fail, so that we can reproduce & test your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Irnzcig, the input data loading is included in the code sample also.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
pml_training_rf_model_1 <- randomForest(classe ~ ., data=pml_training)
pml_training_predictions_1 <- predict(pml_training_rf_model_1, pml_validation)
confusionMatrix(pml_validation$classe, pml_training_predictions_1)
```

Question edited also.